# Jolly Jumper Sequence

Tags: code-golf, sequence

A sequence of n > 0 integers is called a jolly jumper if the absolute values of the difference between successive elements take on all the values 1 through n-1.

So the sequence [4,1,2,4] has absolute differences [3,1,2] which is equivalent to the set [1,2,3] (1 to n-1 where n is the length of original sequence) so it is therefore a jolly jumper.

Sequences have length n>0.

Assume n=1 is a jolly jumper.

*Easy mode:* Don't worry about stdin/stdout. Just a function that accepts arguments however and returns *something* that indicates jolly or not

*Hard mode:* Input on stdin (space separated), and output is "Jolly" / "Not jolly". Capitalization matters.

This is code golf.

EDIT: Sequences can contain negative integers and input on stdin is space separated.

```
$ jolly 2 -1 0 2
Jolly

$ jolly 19 22 24 25
Jolly

$ jolly 19 22 24 21
Not jolly
```

Comment: How is the sequence given?  As a string? "4124"?

Comment: I think space-separated would be the most common convention, so I'll say that.

Comment: You say input is on stdin, but your examples take input as command line arguments. Which should we expect?

Answer (score 3):

### Haskell

### Easy 4 characters

Returns a list of jolly integers if and only if a list of jolly integers is given as input. This is legal based on "Just a function that accepts arguments however and returns something that indicates jolly or not".

```
j=id
```

Alternative easy solution with 61 characters:

Takes in a list and returns the empty list if the sequence is jolly.

```
import List
j n=zipWith(\x->abs.(x-))n(tail n)\\[1..length n]
```

Comment: +1 Good rules lawyering. Although I should point out that in GolfScript the empty program would suffice...

Comment: The alternative solution seems to give wrong result. `[1,3]` is not jolly, is it? I guess you must iterate to `length n-1` instead.

Answer (score 2):

### Golfscript, easy mode, <strike>21</strike> 18 chars

```
{.@-abs\}*;0]$.,,=
```

Accepts arguments as an array of ints on the stack, with nothing else on the stack; leaves 1 on the stack if it's jolly and 0 otherwise. To take input on stdin as a space-separated list of ints, prepend

```
~]
```

and to output "Jolly" / "Not jolly" (assuming that we're turning this into a program) postpend

```
"Not jJ"5/="olly"
```

Comment: I was wondering how this could possibly work -- it took me a moment to realize that when you write "a list of ints on the stack", you really do mean a _list_ of ints (i.e. `[4 1 2 4]`, not `4 1 2 4`).

Comment: @IlmariKaronen, not sure now why I wrote "list". I've edited to "array" to make it clearer.

Answer (score 2):

### Scala, easy mode, 123 characters

```
def j(s:String)={var a=s.sliding(2,1).map(x=>math.abs(x(0)-x(1))).toList
for(c<-1 to a.size)
if(!a.contains(c))false
true}
```

To run or test on ideone.com:

```
object Main
{
   def main(args:Array[String])
   {
      def j(s:String):Boolean=
      {
         var a=s.sliding(2,1).map(x=>math.abs(x(0)-x(1))).toList
         for(c<-1 to a.size)
            if(!a.contains(c)) false
         true
      }
      println(j("4124"))
   }
}
```

Comment: The name could be j instead of jump.

Comment: @user unknown Yes, I know. I realised about half an hour after I posted it that a) I could shorten the method name, and b) I need to use a List instead of a Set, or it won't work properly. :-S

Comment: And the updated rules expect the numbers to be divided by space, 4124 could be one, two, three or 4 numbers.

Comment: @user unknown Oh great. Another person posting a question and then changing the rules half way through.

Comment: I removed return type Boolean, a literal 'return' before `false' and changed Math to math. Saving from 137 to 123.

Answer (score 2):

#### Ruby, <strike>92</strike> 93 characters

The hard version with input on STDIN.

```
f=gets.split.each_cons(2).map{|a|eval(a*?-).abs}.sort
$><<(f==[*1..f.size]??J:"Not j")+"olly"
```

If you start it with `-pa` (counts as 4) you can save 5 chars:

```
f=$F.each_cons(2).map{|a|eval(a*?-).abs}.sort
$_=(f==[*1..f.size]??J:"Not j")+"olly"
```

Comment: Ah, nice improvement. Didn't realize there was an each_cons method.

Comment: I just realized that this fails when the sequence is a single digit. You'd have to stick with f.size instead f[-1].

Comment: Oh, you can also save 5 characters if you run it with options `-pa` .

Answer (score 2):

## Java (Hard)

Assumes that input is given through stdin. (not through command line arguments as per example)

**Golfed - 325**

```
class JollyJumper {
public static void main(String[] args) {
String[] in = new Scanner(System.in).nextLine().split(" ");
int[] j=new int[in.length-1],k=j.clone();
for(int i=0;i<in.length-1;i++){j[i]=Math.abs(Integer.parseInt(in[i])-Integer.parseInt(in[i+1]));k[i]=i+1;}
Arrays.sort(j);System.out.println(Arrays.equals(j, k)?"Jolly":"Not jolly");
}
}
```

**Un-Golfed**

```
public class JollyJumper {
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
    int[] jolly;
    String[] in;

    in = sc.nextLine().split(" ");
    jolly = new int[in.length-1];

    for (int i = 0; i < in.length-1; i++)
        jolly[i] = Math.abs(Integer.parseInt(in[i]) - Integer.parseInt(in[i+1]));

    Arrays.sort(jolly);

    for (int i = 1; i <= in.length-1; i++) {
        if (jolly[i-1] != i) {
            System.out.println("Not jolly");
            return;
        }
    }
    System.out.println("Jolly");
}
}
```

Answer (score 2):

## J (easy), 18

```
(i.@#-:<:/:])|2-/\
```

```
   (i.@#-:<:/:])|2-/\2 _1 0 2
1
   (i.@#-:<:/:])|2-/\19 22 24 25
1
   (i.@#-:<:/:])|2-/\19 22 24 21
0
```

## J (hard), 68

```
2!:55]1!:2&2'olly',~>('Not j';'J'){~(i.@#-:<:/:])|2-/\".@>2}.ARGV_j_
```

```
$ jconsole jumper.ijs 2 -1 0 2
Jolly
$ jconsole jumper.ijs 19 22 24 25
Jolly
$ jconsole jumper.ijs 2 19 22 24 21
Not jolly
```

Answer (score 2):

## [Brachylog](https://github.com/JCumin/Brachylog), 11 bytes (easy)

```
s₂ᶠ-ᵐȧᵐo~⟦₁
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##SypKTM6ozMlPN/r/v/hRU9PDbQt0H26dcGI5kMivezR/2aOmxv//o410FOINdRQMdBSMYv8DAA)

`s₂ᶠ-ᵐ` - Consecutive differences

`ȧᵐ` - Absolute values

`o` - Sort

`~⟦₁` - Is the result the range 1 to something?

Answer (score 1):

## D

### easy (<s>103</s> 83 chars)

returns sum of 1..i.length on Jolly some other number if not (a bit of rules laywering here)

```
import std.math;auto jolly(I)(I i){int t,l;foreach(r;i){t+=abs(l-r);l=r;}return t;}
```

### hard (142 chars)

input is whitespace delimited and ends on EOF

```
import std.stdio;import std.math; void main(){int i,j,l,t;while(readf("%d ",&i)>0){t+=abs(l-i);l=i;j++;}write(t==j*++j/2?"J":"Not j","olly");}
```

Answer (score 1):

### J, 30 <strike>26</strike> easy mode, 81 <strike>76</strike> hard mode

*edit:* handle lists shorter than 3, fix stdin reading

First line takes care of easy mode, second adds hard mode.

```
j=:[:*/[:(>:@i.@#=/:~)[:|2-/\]
exit('olly',~[:>('Not j';'J'){~[:j 0".}:)&.stdin''
```

J reads generally right-to-left:

`2-/\` : for every two successive numbers in the list, take the difference

`|` : absolute value

`/:~` : sort in ascending order

`>:@i.@#` : 1 to *n*, for a list of *n* numbers

`=` : compare the sorted differences with the sequence (using a J "fork")

`*/` : multiply all the element-wise booleans; if all the comparisons were 1, their product is 1, so it's jolly

Comment: Consider input `1 3`.

Comment: Thanks, @Peter.  Fixed...and still not competitive with your Golfscript. Well done.

Answer (score 1):

#### Scala easy:138  <strike>153, 170</strike> (was errornous, improved later)

```
def j(i:String)={
def a(s:Seq[Int])=(s zip s.tail).map(x=>(x._2-x._1))
a(a(i.split(" ").map(_.toInt)).map(math.abs).sorted).toSet.size==1}
```

ungolfed:

```
def jolly (input: String) = { 
      val list = input.split (" ").map (_.toInt)

      def stepsize (s: Seq[Int]) = 
        (s zip s.tail).map (x=> (x._2 - x._1))

      val first = stepsize (input.split (" ").map (_.toInt))
      val pos = first.map (math.abs)
      val unique = stepsize (pos.sorted).toSet
      (unique.size) == 1
}
```

The idea is, that we build the second derivation:

```
Original: 4 1 2 4
Stepsize:  -3 1 2 (first)
     abs:   3 1 2
  sorted:   1 2 3 
Stepsize:     1 1 
  to Set:       1 
    size:       1
```

#### Scala hard 172  <strike>182,  205</strike> (was errornous/improved):

```
def j{
def a(s:Seq[Int])=(s zip s.tail).map(x=>(x._2-x._1))
println((if(a(a(readLine.split(" ").map(_.toInt)).map(math.abs).sorted).toSet.size==1)"J"else"Not j")+"olly")}
j
```

more or less the same as above.

Comment: Input `4 1 2 5` returns true. Still haven't managed to get my head around that left fold though...

Comment: Oh yes, I found my error. Need to correct it.

Comment: `readLine` takes input from the console, not the stdin... (but you can use `args` instead)

Comment: And `j("1")` throws `UnsupportedOperationException: empty.max`

Comment: Pardon - how do you define the difference between stdin and "input from the console"?

Comment: What I meant was, if you run your script with `scala jolly.scala 19 22 24 25` then it won't work, but I suppose you could pipe it in from a file with `scala jolly.scala < numbers.txt` and `readLine` would work. In any case your hard version doesn't work as given above - try pasting in REPL

Comment: `echo "19 22 24 25" | scala -i jolly.scala` is the readline-approach. `scala jolly.scala 19 22 24 25` is 'using parameters' or 'arguments'. The version didn't work; maybe it was a transfer error. For "1", it is still buggy.

Comment: You are right regarding readLine; I was looking at the example in the OP, which is contradictory

Comment: That might be right for the `Easy mode: Don't worry about stdin/stdout.` only, yes.

Answer (score 1):

### Ruby, 97 <strike>102</strike> <strike>106</strike> (hard)

Might as well, since everyone else is:

```
h,*t=gets.split
d=t.map{|i|h,i=i,h;eval(i+?-+h).abs}.sort
$><<(d==[*1..d.size]??J:"Not j")+"olly"
```

Input taken on stdin.

Comment: You can replace `(1..d.size).to_a` by `[*1..d.size]`. Switching operands is now possible, saves another one (total -5 chars).

Comment: @Howard Oh, so that's how you do it! I've been trying to figure out a golf way to convert ranges to arrays for a while now. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

## Groovy

### Easy: 78

```
j={m=[];it[1..-1].inject(it[0]){p,n->m<<p-n;n};m*.abs().sort()==1..<it.size()}

assert [[2, -1, 0, 2,], [19, 22, 24, 25], [19, 22, 24, 21]].collect { j(it) } == [true, true, false]
```

### Hard: 151

```
j={m=[];it[1..-1].inject(it[0]){p,n->m<<p-n;n};m*.abs().sort()==1..<it.size()};System.in.eachLine{println "${j(it.split()*.toLong())?'J':'Not j'}olly"}
```

Answer (score 1):

### PowerShell, hard, 117 <s>126</s>

```
('Not j','J')["$(($a=-split$input)|%{if($x-ne$0){[math]::abs($x-$_)}$x=$_}|sort)"-eq"$(1..($a.Count-1)|sort)"]+'olly'
```

History:

- 2011-11-18 17:54 (**123**, −3) – Changed `$null` to a non-existent variable
- 2011-11-18 18:02 (**117**, −6) – inlined all variable declarations

Answer (score 1):

## Scala

A quick stab - there are probably improvements possible.

### Easy: 77

```
def j(? :Int*)=(?tail,?).zipped.map(_-_).map(math.abs).sorted==(1 to?.size-1)
```

### Hard: 124

```
val? =args.map(_.toInt)toSeq;print(if((?tail,?).zipped.map(_-_).map(math.abs).sorted==(1 to?.size-1))"Jolly"else"Not jolly")
```

Comment: Ok - we're lost, Luigi found us! :) Welcome on CodeGolf. Immediately I start learning something. Question mark as identifier? Whooo - who allowed that? :)

Comment: Yes, and all to shave 1 character off! It's the difference between an alphanumeric characters and *operator characters* (see http://stackoverflow.com/q/7656937/770361) which means you can sometimes omit spaces (but sometimes need extra ones) and dots. Code golf is great for learning though - a bit like aerobatics for flying.

Answer (score 1):

## Q, 64 (hard), 30 (easy)

hard

```
{$[(1_(!)(#)x)~asc abs 1_(-':)x;(-1"Jolly";);(-1"Not jolly";)];}
```

easy

```
{(1_(!)(#)x)~asc abs 1_(-':)x}
```

Answer (score 1):

### J (easy), 19 characters

```
*/(=i.@#)<:/:~|2-/\
```

Usage:

```
    */(=i.@#)<:/:~|2-/\4 2 1 4
1
```

Vary similar to [DCharness's answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/3614/737), and I would have just added it as a comment but for the fact that he hasn't visited since the 23rd of February.

`2-/\` takes the difference between successive pairs of numbers,

`|` gets the absolute value of each number,

`/:~` sorts into ascending order,

`<:` decrements each number by 1,

`(=i.@#)` a [J hook](http://www.jsoftware.com/help/learning/09.htm) which generates the sequence of numbers from 0 to the length of the differences list - 1 (`i.@#`) and compares it with that list `=`.

`*/` multiples the list of `1`s and `0`s generated by the previous verb.

Comment: Didn't realize until after I submitted my answer: we took the same approach, but I used `x-:y` instead of `*/x=y` to save a character.

Answer (score 1):

## PHP, easy, 129

For a given array `$s` of integers:

```
for($i=1;$i<count($s);$i++)$a[abs($s[$i]-$s[$i-1])]=1;
for($i=1;$i<count($s);$i++)if(!isset($a[$i]))die('Not Jolly');echo 'Jolly';
```

The ungolfed version:

```
for( $i=1; $i<count( $s ); $i++ )
    $a[ abs( $s[$i] - $s[$i-1] ) ] = 1;

for( $i=1; $i < count($s); $i++ )
    if( !isset( $a[$i] ) )
        die( 'Not Jolly' );

echo "Jolly";
```

Answer (score 1):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), <strike>7</strike> 6 bytes (easy)

```
IAṢ⁼J$
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0rNyan8/9/T8eHORY8a93ip/P//30hH11DHQMcIAA)

```
IAṢ⁼J$    jolly function on N:
IAṢ       the increment list: get all the Increments, take their Absolute values, and Ṣort them
   ⁼      compare that to...
    J$    range from 1 to len(N) -- this has an extra number, but that's fine because...
          ...the increment list is one shorter, and ⁼ will only compare that many values
```

Takes input as comma-separated numbers in the first argument. Returns 1 if the sequence is jolly, and 0 if it isn't!

**7-byte solution:**

```
LRṖḟIA$
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0rNyan8/98n6OHOaQ93zPd0VPn//7@Rjq6hjoGOEQA)

Takes input as comma-separated numbers in the first argument. Returns nothing if the list is a jolly jumper sequence, and *something* if it isn't.

Adding this line makes it work with the hard spec:

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), <strike>27</strike> 22 bytes (hard, feedback welcome!)

```
ɠḲVIAṢ⁼J$ị“¢⁼D“¡KṀȥƘạ»
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0rNyan8///kgoc7NoV5Oj7cuehR4x4vlYe7ux81zDkE4riAGAu9H@5sOLH02IyHuxYe2v3/v5GCrqGCgYIRAA)

```
ɠḲVIAṢ⁼J$ị“¢⁼D“¡KṀȥƘạ»
ɠḲV                     read a line, split on spaces and eValuate the numbers
   IAṢ⁼J$               jolly function: see above!
         ị              ịndex the result into (remember Jelly is one-indexed, so 0 wraps around to the back):
          “¢⁼D“          "Jolly" compressed if true,
              ¡KṀȥƘạ»   or, "Not jolly" compressed if false!
```

**27-byte (hard) solution:**

```
LRṖḟIA$
ɠḲVÇ“¡KṀȥƘạ»“¢⁼D»L?
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##AUQAu/9qZWxsef//TFLhuZbhuJ9JQSQKyaDhuLJWw4figJzCoUvhuYDIpcaY4bqhwrvigJzCouKBvETCu0w///8yIC0xIDAgMg)

Takes space-separated numbers on `stdin`, and outputs "Jolly" or "Not jolly".

Explanation:

```
LRṖḟIA$               jolly function:
LRP                   make a range (R) from 1 to the input length (L), popping off (P) the last number to make it 1 to N-1.
   ḟ                  reverse filter: remove all the elements from that range that are members of...
    IA$               the increment list: get all the increments, take their absolute values (expressed as one monad via '$').
ɠḲVÇ“¡KṀȥƘạ»“¢⁼D»L?    i/o main function:
ɠḲV                   read a line from stdin, split it on spaces and have Python parse each number (handling negative signs)
   Ç             ?    run the above, and use the result on the following conditional:
                L?    if the length of the result is truthy (non-empty):
    “¡KṀȥƘạ»          then, return Jelly compressed string "Not jolly",
            “¢⁼D»     else, return Jelly compressed string "Jolly".
```

Any feedback much appreciated!

Comment: `LR` is `J`. If you write something like `IAṢ⁼J$` you get a nice 1/0 result, and you can use that to index into `“Not jolly“Jolly”`: `ɠḲVIAṢ⁼J$ị“¢⁼D“¡KṀȥƘạ»`

Comment: @Lynn Thank you, that's much better! Clever trick with the one-indexed wrapping around, and I learned more about the `⁼` atom too, handy to compare just parts of lists.

Answer (score 1):

## [Haskell](https://www.haskell.org/), <s>59</s> 57 bytes

```hs
f n=all(`elem`map abs(zipWith(-)n$tail n))[1..length n-1]
```

Easy mode, returns jollyness as a boolean. Thanks to @Laikoni for two bytes.

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##ZYsxDgIhEEV7TzGFBSQDCWQtLPYI1haEuJiwQhwmxKXy8oiF29j8vPeSn8L2jES9r8BzIBJLpFiWEiqE@ybeuV5zS0JJPraQCVhKZ7SmyI@WgJXxvYTMMMO4XG4g6itz06s8ADhwBi2qMX4o7mp2nX50RmvRTmjNXzl9i@8f)

Answer (score 1):

## [Japt](https://github.com/ETHproductions/japt), <s>32</s> 30 bytes Hard

*-2 Bytes from @Shaggy*

```
`not jo¥y`s4*Näa n äa e¥1
hUÎu
```

[Try it online!](https://ethproductions.github.io/japt/?v=1.4.6&code=YG5vdCBqb6V5YHM0Kk7kYSBuIORhIGWlMQpoVc51&input=MiAtMSAwIDI=)

Comment: [30 bytes](https://ethproductions.github.io/japt/?v=1.4.6&code=YG5vdCBqb6V5YHM0Kk7kYSBuIORhIGWlMQpoVc51&input=MiAtMSAwIDI=). I only noticed the capitalisation requirement at the last second so can probably be improved further.

Answer (score 1):

### Python 3, 117 (hard)

```python
l=[*map(int,input().split())]
print(["Not j","J"][{abs(a-b)for a,b in zip(l[1:],l[:-1])}=={*range(1,len(l))}]+"olly")
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##DcgxDsIgFADQ3VP8MP1fwUjdmnCBDl6AMNCkKuYLhOJQm54dO73k5bW@Ury1xsZ2H58xxCpDzN@KdFkyh0Nyp1yORyvuqcJbSDEKZzc/LejVRI9UwMsJQoRfyMhWD06yHZR2tBuzdcXH54xa8hyRiXZ3Fol5FdRaD0rDFfo/)

Comment: There is an error in your program. [Try it online](https://tio.run/##DcixDsIgEADQ3a@4MN1VMFK3Jv6Agz9AGGhSFXMehOJQm347dnrJy0t9Jbm0xlfXfULGKFVHyd@KdJozx13yh1z2R6duSqt7qvBW3q1hnDGYkR6pQNAjRIFfzMjODl6zG4z1tJm1K0GeE1rNkyATbf6oEvOiqLUejIUz9H8)

Comment: This gives the wrong answer for the first test case. Please check your program for the test cases contained in the question.

Comment: Feel ashamed, cause when fixed wrong version forgot to reverse outputs ;(

Comment: Welcome to PPCG!!

Answer (score 0):

### JavaScript: 105 (easy mode)

[Golfed:](http://jsfiddle.net/briguy37/vhjdx/)

```
function a(l){for(r=i=1;i<(m=l.length);i++){for(j=t=0;j+1<m;)t+=(d=l[j]-l[++j])*d==i*i;t||(r=0)}return r}
```

[Un-golfed:](http://jsfiddle.net/briguy37/6f6y6/)

```
function isJolly(list){
    //Iterate over i to list.length-1
    for(r=i=1;i<(length=list.length);i++){
        //Check the differences between all consecutive elements squared minus i squared.  Set t to true if one was found.
        for(j=t=0;j+1<length;)t+=(diff=list[j]-list[++j])*diff==i*i;

        //if t is not true, return value is 0
        t||(r=0)
    }
    return r
}
```

Answer (score 0):

### Perl, 89 (hard)

86 characters of code + 3 for running with the `-p` option

```
@a=0;$a[abs($1-$2)]=1while s/(\S+) (\S+)/$2/;$_='Jolly';(grep{!defined}@a)&&s/J/Not j/
```

Answer (score 0):

### [Javascript (hard): 138](http://jsfiddle.net/AFk2W/)

```
a=prompt().split(" ")
i=0;b=[];c=[]
while(b[i]=Math.abs(a[i]-a[++i]),c[i-1]=i,i<a.length-1);b.sort()
alert(b+""==c+""?"Jolly":"Not jolly")
```

Answer (score 0):

### Python, 255 characters

```
r=[19,22,24,25]
i=0
k=[ i+1 for i in range(len(r)-1)]
def jolly(a):
    p=[]
    i=0
    while i<len(a)-1: 
       p.append(abs(a[i+1]-a[i]))
       i+=1
    p.sort() 
    if p==k:
       return 'jolly'
    else:
       return 'Not jolly'

print(jolly(r))
```

Comment: I've added the language name and character count to your answer (it runs as Python so that's what I assume it is). The character count I've given is the one give by the [userscript](http://meta.codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/170/code-golf-userscript-to-help-in-navigating-the-site-v0-37-now-available). You could probably cut down the first indentation level to one space to save some characters here.

Answer (score 0):

### R, Easy, 110

```
f=function(s){p=NULL;l=length;for (i in 2:l(s))p=c(p,abs(s[i]-s[i-1]));ifelse(all(sort(p)==(1:(l(s)-1))),1,0)}
```

Usage:

```
f(c(2, -1, 0, 2))
[1] 1
f(c(19, 22, 24, 25))
[1] 1
f(c(19, 22, 24, 21))
[1] 0
```

Answer (score 0):

### Python, 72 (easy), 114 (hard)

**Easy:**

```
def f(a):return len(set(map(lambda x,y:abs(x-y),a[1:],a[:-1])))>len(a)-2
```

**Hard**:

```
a=map(int,raw_input().split())
print('Not j','J')[len(set(map(lambda x,y:abs(x-y),a[1:],a[:-1])))>len(a)-2]+'olly'
```

Answer (score 0):

## C, 119(hard), 97(easy)

```
b,c,a[];main(k){while(~scanf("%d",a+c))k=c++;for(c=k;b<c*c;)k-abs(a[b%c]-a[b++%c+1])?:k--;puts(k?"Not jolly":"Jolly");}
```

The easy solution reads the input from the arguments and returns a 0 as exit code if the input is a jolly jumper sequence:

```
i,k;main(int c,char**a){for(k=c-=2,a++;i<c*c;)k-abs(atoi(a[i%c])-atoi(a[i++%c+1]))?:k--;exit(k);}
```

Answer (score 0):

### APL (<s>50</s> <s>49</s> 47, hard)

```
'Not jolly' 'Jolly'[1+K[⍋K←¯1↓|Z-1⌽Z]≡¯1↓⍳⍴Z←⎕]
```

Easy (24):

```
{K[⍋K←¯1↓|⍵-1⌽⍵]≡¯1↓⍳⍴⍵}
```

The function takes an array and returns 0 or 1.

Answer (score 0):

## [Japt](https://github.com/ETHproductions/japt), <s>11</s> 10 bytes

```
Êo1 eUäa n
```

[Run it online](https://ethproductions.github.io/japt/?v=1.4.5&code=ym8xIGVV5GEgbg==&input=WzE5IDIyIDI0IDI1XQ==)

*Saved 1 byte thanks to Shaggy*

Comment: [10 bytes](https://ethproductions.github.io/japt/?v=1.4.5&code=ym8xIGVV5GEgbg==&input=WzE5LDIyLDI0LDI1XQ==)